# Getting maximum values of columns with 'date/datetime' datatype from all tables of all databases

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-schema, information-schema

Consider this--there are many databases, and each database has many tables. I extracted the columns with 'date/datetime' datatype along with table name and schema name .

```sql
 SELECT
    c.column_name AS col,
    column_type AS type,
    c.table_name AS tn,
    c.table_schema AS ts
FROM
    information_schema.columns AS c,
    (SELECT
        table_name, table_schema, table_rows AS tr
    FROM
        information_schema.TABLES
    ORDER BY table_schema) a
WHERE
    column_type LIKE 'date%'
        AND a.table_name = c.table_name
        AND a.table_schema = c.table_schema
;
```

and I got these columns = (column,column_type,table_name,table_Schema). Now I want to loop inside the result(or any other way will be fine) and for each row I want to do this

```sql
SELECT max(column) FROM table_schema.table_name
```

For example, first row is (login_date,date,login,customers), and I want to do

```sql
SELECT max(login_date) FROM customers.login
```

and I want to do it for every row. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: take a look of stored procedures, temporary tables and cursors.

Comment: Are you trying to find out when a table was last updated? In that case, something like this should do the trick: `SELECT UPDATE_TIME
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbname'
   AND TABLE_NAME = 'tabname'`

Comment: No , i do not want to find when a table was last updated . It is a very abstracted question , a smaller part of what i wanted to do . I just wanted to find the maximum value of every column with date/datetime datatype.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
 cursor csr 
    is select max(dates)
    from tables
    and dates is not null; rec csr%rowtype;

    begin 
    open csr; 
    for x in cursor_body 
    loop
    fetch csr into rec;
    exit when csr%notfound;
    x.csr;
    end loop;
    close csr;
```

The just of it is that you are going to have to use at least a declare block if you don't want to create a full on procedure. Select the values in your cursor and then loop the cursor in the processing stage after begin.

Hope this helps

Comment: is it possible without using stored procedure / cursor?